# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and Default Scope

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Is there a way to add a default scope to a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract based model.

I want to be able to query a model with some conditions taken as default.

e.g.

- deleted = false
- order name asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract:: _fetch()` method and modify the generated `Zend_Db_Table_Select` in there before retrieving the rows from the database adapter. As far as I know all `fetch*`-methods and `find()` in `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` boil down to this generic row-retrieval-method (besides `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::fetchNew()` naturally), so your modified code will be called everytime rows are retrieved from the database.

```
/**
 * Support method for fetching rows.
 *
 * @param  Zend_Db_Table_Select $select  query options.
 * @return array An array containing the row results in FETCH_ASSOC mode.
 */
protected function _fetch(Zend_Db_Table_Select $select)
{
    $select->where('deleted = false')->order('name asc');
    return parent:: _fetch($select);
}
```

Comment: I read this earlier here but cant seem to get it working :S
http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/2008/01/30/zend_db_table_abstract-in-version-15/

very odd

Comment: What does "cant seem to get it working" mean? Are you getting error messages or wrong results or nor result at all? Have you tried to debug what's going on?

Comment: Try adding a var_dump($select->__toString()) in the method above - just before the call to the parent method and look what the generated SQL string looks like.

Comment: the var_dump reveals that it is putting the scope into the sql... but it causes calls to findDependentRowset to fail.

Comment: Do you get any error message on calling findDependentRowset()?

Comment: The scope works perfectly when querying the model directly. But when I try to access the model through findDependentRowset() none of the scope I set up in the model is used. findDependentRowset() must use a different fetch action maybe?

Comment: It's weird it does use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::_fetch() so it shouldn't reset the query, try to add some var_dumps directly on the method in the Zend Class to see where it's losing the value.

Comment: I resolved the problem. The scope was working correctly! I am an idiot and had a column called TIMESTAMP, so instead of ordering by TIMESTAMP I had to order by TableName.TIMESTAMP.